# Analyzing binary survey data - after clustering, how move forward in multivariate/ordination analysis?

Tags: clustering, binary-data

I am new to multivariate analysis.

I have been given a set of survey answers with around 120 binary questions. My goal is to first perform cluster analysis to find the optimal number of respondent "types".

In the next step, I want to analyze what distinguishes the different clusters within correlation between different "trait" occurences and which traits (i.e. survey answers) often appear together in different clusters.

I am new to this type of ordination analysis, and wondered if anyone can point me in the direction of good resources. I can imagine that community ecology (species presence/absence data) might do similar things.